# How to insert single quote and comma in one column

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, ms-access-2007

My code is as below '''a','b','c'''.

```
Dim abc As String = "''a','b','c''"
sqlselect.Connection = con
sqlselect.CommandText = "insert into table1(Name1) values ('" & abc  & "')"
```

It gives the error:

> Syntax error (missing operator)

in the query expression

Comment: why not use parametric queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use parametrized query not string concatenation

```
Dim a As String = "'a', 'b', 'c'"

sqlselect.Connection = con
sqlselect.CommandText = "insert into table1(Name1) values (@a)"
sqlselect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a)
sqlselect.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This assuming you have only one column named `Name1`.

The parametrized queries are the only way to go because they offer protection against [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain) and help you treating the parsing of strings, dates, decimal numbers

Comment: Of course. Use always parametrized query. There are very few exceptions to this rule.